# How many mac addresses there are in PCI multi port ethernet cards?

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

I'm thinking of buy a multi port ethernet card like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833310504). But i don't know how many macc address there are in this card. Are there four mac addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought an ethernet card (multi port) there are one more mac addresses for each port. May be useful for someone.